# application of Minkowski's inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Hi: I'm reading a proof and I don't understand one of the steps. The theorem supposes the following:

$E(X^2_{thi})^{1+\delta} < \triangle < \infty$ for some $\delta > 0 $ and all $h = 1, \ldots p, ~i = 1, \ldots k$, and all $t$.

Then, it starts off the proof by saying the following:

By Minkowski's inequality:

$E \left|\sum_{h=1}^{p} X_{thi} X_{thj}\right|^{1+\delta} \le \left|\sum_{h=1}^{p} (E|X_{thi} X_{thj}| ^{(1+\delta)})^\left(\frac{1}{1+\delta}\right)\right| ^{1+\delta}$

Can someone show or explain how the relation above is obtained from A) the stated assumption and B) Minkowski's inequality ( or any other inequality in case it's a typo and it's using some other inequality ). The rest of the proof makes sense so no need to state the rest.

Minkowski's inequality is :

Let $q \ge 1$. If $E(|Y|^q) < \infty $ and  $E(|Z|^q) < \infty $, then

$\left(E|Y + Z|^{q}\right)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) \le E(|Y|^q)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) + E(|Z|^q)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)$

Thanks.

Comment: Let $q=1+δ$ and raise both sides of Minkowski's Inequality to the q power.

Comment: I got the answer from someone in an email so I posted above for anyone who is interested.